# How to authenticate requests to images in an angularJS app using an access_token

Tags: angularjs, security, cookies

I have an angularJS application whose authentication system is made with an `access_token` and communicating with a backend server written in Go

Therefore to authenticate the user, I have to add the `access_token` to each request `?access_token=SomeTokenHere` or via a header `Access-Token: SomeTokenHere`

It works great.

The issue is that my backend serves protected images, and I cannot put the access token in the image src for some security reasons(If the user copy/paste the link to someone else, the access_token would be given too ...)

What I'd like to do is to inject a header containing my access token, but since the request is made from the browser it doesn't possible.

This could probably be possible with a cookie, but I'd to avoid using a cookie especially because the angularApp and the backend are not on the same sub-domain.

Another idea would be to create a directive that would get the raw data, and set the data to the image. First I don't know if this is possible and is it a good idea for hundreds of images in the webpage ?

If you have any idea, I'd be glad to hear from you !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical problem, and fortunately it was already solved - for example on Amazon S3.

Solution idea is simple: instead of directly using secret key - you can generate signature with access policy, using that key.

There is good algorithm designed especially to generate signatures for this purpose - [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

You can have one secret key on your server and use it to sign every image URL before it would be sent to client, also you can add some additional policies like url expiration time...

Comment: Indeed HMAC signature could solve that, but I wanted to make sure the image couldn't be get even if the user copy/paste the link to someone else. The second issue is that generating hundreds of signatures at the same time is not free, and would slow down the request processing.

Comment: About link copy/paste - one of possible, maybe partial, solution is to check referrer request header, and deny all requests that came from other domains(this is typical way to prevent images hotlinking). About signature generation time - it is not free, but hashing itself is quite fast(near thousand of hashes per few ms), so likely it would not be much noticeable in comparison to other computations during request. (if you want to test openssl hashing implementation performance on your own hardware - you can use `openssl speed sha1` command).

Comment: Interesting. I'll do some tests about that. In the meantime, I'll let the question opened but I'll accept it later if no one else contributes :-)